# position images within a div and then position div at bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to position images  in my footer.
Problem that is according when i keep position attribute other than absolute than images get beyond the boundaries of the footer and footer stick at the top.
 when i keep footer position absolute then i have to **specific position in pixel but height of content varies** and i can't give specific position.

```
<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

  <footer class="effect5">
    <img id="fb" src="../images/fbfooter.jpg" />
    <img id="email" src="../images/emailfooter.jpg" />
    <img id="help" src="../images/helpfooter.jpg" />
    <img id="need" src="../images/needfooter.jpg" />
    <img id="tos" src="../images/tosfooter.jpg" />
    <img id="twit" src="../images/twitfooter.jpg" />
  </footer>
</body>
```

Css is

```
footer{

  margin:auto;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-1850px;

  background-image:url(../images/fbg.jpg);
  height:360px;
  width:1282px;
  /*background-size*/

  -webkit-background-size:100% 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow:15px 15px 20px #35707E;
  border-top-left-radius:100px 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:100px 100px;
}

img[id=fb]{
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:600px;
  margin-top:150px;

  -webkit-box-shadow:5px 5px 20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

img[id=fb]:hover{

}
```

And so on...

Comment: why do you have `bottom:-1850px;`? also CSS has an id selector `#`

Comment: bottom: -1850px; because i'm providing absolute positing of the footer,that's wrong that is the problem and img[id=fb] is faster

Comment: I'm sorry but your problem description is not very clear, can you provide us a reproducible example in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfidle.net) or a link to your site? also do you have any source to back up your claim that attribute selector is faster?

Comment: link is http://www.collegememo.net/fun/collegefun.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should google sticky footer or have a look at [this one](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)
and then you can use relative positioning within the footer.

Comment: sticky footer always stay at bottom u can only use sticky footer when your footer has less height!! and no images..

Comment: What do you mean when your footer has less height? The sticky footer works with images too, I have successfully implemented it before. The only condition is  that the negative margin value should always equal the full height of the footer (including any padding or borders you may add). Have a look here: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/